# Formatting JSON response

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

**====Summary====**

I need some help trying to format my JSON response. I'm using ASP.Net with a Model and a Controller.

**====Information====**

I am working on a web api in ASP.Net. I have a SQL backend in which I fetch some data and put it into a DataTable. My DataTable looks like this:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| ID | Title | Users |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | Test  | user1 |
|  1 | Test  | user2 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

NOTE: One record can have multiple users which is why ID is "1" for both rows ("ID" is not the unique ID of the actual SQL table row but rather a foreign key...anyway, I digress... )

I have created a Model in C# that looks like this:

```
    public class Record
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Title {get; set;}
            public string Users {get; set;}
        }
```

Finally my Controller looks like this

```
 DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper();

    public IEnumerable Get_Record(string id)
    {
        // Get DataTable
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = db.GetRecord(id);

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            yield return new Record
            {
                ID = row.Field("ID"),
                Title = row.Field("Title"),
                Users = row.Field("Users")
            };
        }

    }
```

When I call the API I get this:

```
    [
      -{
         ID: 1,
         Title: "Test",
         Users: "user1"
       },

      -{
         ID: 1,
         Title: "Test",
         Users: "user2"
       }
    ]
```

**====QUESTION====**

How would I get the JSON response to look something sort of like this (if possible):

```
    {
     "Response":
       [
        {
          ID: 1,
          Title: "Test",
          Users: 
           [
             {name: "user1"},
             {name: "user2"}
           ]
        }
       ]
    }
```

If that is not possible then this would be great as well:

```
    "Response":
    [
      {
         ID: 1,
         Title: "Test",
         Users: "user1"
      },

      {
         ID: 1,
         Title: "Test",
         Users: "user2"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: You need an object with a member named "Response" that is an array of type `Record`.  As for the pretty formatting, not sure about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand upon @Shahrooz Jefri's answer, you can return an `HttpResponseMessage` which will allow you to return an anonymous object, but to get the result formatted as required, you will need to modify the `Get_Record` method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get_Record(string id)
{
    // Get DataTable
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = db.GetRecord(id);

    var records = dt.Rows.Select(r => new Record()
    {
        ID = row.Field("ID"),
        Title = row.Field("Title"),
        Users = row.Field("Users")
    });

    return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
        new
        {
            Response = new
            {
                ID = records.First().ID,
                Title = records.First().Title,
                Users = records.Select(r => r.Users)
            }
        });
}
```

With this approach, we first transform the results from a call to `db.GetRecord` into an `IEnumerable<Record>` of your your `Record` object.

From there, we can shape an anonymous object to match your formatting requirements. Note that in my answer I have not applied any error checking; you should, as the case where `db.GetRecord` returns no results will cause an exception when we populate the `ID` and `Title` fields of the response object due to calls to `records.First()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can return your own format with anonymous Object.

Please See this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    return this.Request.CreateResponse(
        HttpStatusCode.OK,
        new { Message = "Hello", Value = 123 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, What I have experienced so far, creating a generic response will be the best practice for your case. For instance, you may have a class something like this.

```
public enum Status
{
    OK = 1,
    ERROR = -1,
}

public class ResponseDTO
{
    public static ResponseDTO CreateDynamicResponse(object content)
    {
        return new ResponseDTO {Status = Status.OK, Content = content};
    }

    public static ResponseDTO CreateDynamicResponseFromException(RovlerBaseException ex)
    {
        return new ResponseDTO
        {
            Status = Status.ERROR,
            Message = ex.Message,
        };
    }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)] 
    public Status Status;

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public object Content { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

After the execution of action I create an ActionFilterAttribute in order to check if there is an error on response that action just returned. Then I user `CreateDynamicResponse` or `CreateDynamicResponseFromException` with respect to the status of returned object.